# Multiple ManyToMany 'in' query with Django

Tags: python, django, django-q

I've simplified the models for the question, but essentially I'm trying to perform a query with the following models:

```
class mod1(models.Model):
    mod1_id = CharField(unique=True, ...)

class mod2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.ManyToManyField(mod1)
```

So any `mod2` object can have x number of mod1s...in this case I have a `mod2` object that has four `mod1` objects attached to it with the `mod1_ids` of "foo", "bar", "fizz", and "bang". If I have two different lists of mod1_ids, can I make separate Q objects of the lists to perform the filter so it returns my mod2 object? I've tried it and so far it hasn't yielded anything. Assume I can't combine the lists of ids to form one list. What I've tried:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Q1 = Q(field2__mod1_id__in=["foo"])
Q2 = Q(field2__mod1_id__in=["bar", "fizz"]

len(mod2.objects.filter(Q1 & Q2))
>>> 0
```

When I perform those queries individually, they both work, but together they don't. Can someone please help me out here? Thank you.

Comment: This question is answered in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400746/django-q-queries-on-the-same-field). The biggest difference is only the contains condition `Q(...__in=[...])` instead of equality `Q(...=...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You query make:

```
field2__mod1_id__in=["foo"] AND field2__mod1_id__in=["bar", "fizz"]
```

but You need:

```
field2__mod1_id__in=["foo"] OR field2__mod1_id__in=["bar", "fizz"]
```

if yes, use:

```
mod2.objects.filter(Q1 | Q2)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

## EDIT:

Sets `["foo"]` and `["bar", "fizz"]` are exclusive. Don't have common part. The `AND` operator always return `[]`.

Solution:

Query You need:

```
field2__mod1_id__in=["foo", "bar", "fizz"]
```

Python:

```
mod1sets = ["foo"]
mod1sets.append("bar")
mod1sets.append("fizz")

len(mod2.objects.filter(field2__mod1_id__in=mod1sets))
```

Comment: Thank, this make sense but still not what I want. I want to query to see if it has both of them only, not one or the other.

Comment: Excuse a late comment. The question was for a queryset like for families that have one boy and one girl or more sons and daughters. It was a correct question even that a child boy and girl are exclusive. :-) I wrote an answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400746/django-q-queries-on-the-same-field) because this type conditions generate a multiple join with huge searched Cartesian product set, if the condition is not separated to a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will genearte new Q object which satisfies

```
field2__mod1_id__in=["foo"] AND field2__mod1_id__in=["bar", "fizz"]
```

Your mod2 object is having only one object that does not satisfy this condition.